# Printing a large string takes too much time in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, algorithm

I was trying out a problem at codeforces and got stuck while printing the solution.The Problem link is:-[Problem Link](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/349/B)

> Igor has fallen in love with Tanya. 
>       Now Igor wants to show his feelings and write a number on the fence opposite to Tanya's house. 
>       Igor thinks that the larger the number is, the more chance to win Tanya's heart he has.
>
> Unfortunately, Igor could only get v liters of paint. 
>       He did the math and concluded that digit d requires ad liters of paint. 
>       Besides, Igor heard that Tanya doesn't like zeroes. That's why Igor won't use them in his number.
>
> Help Igor find the maximum number he can write on the fence.
>
> Input:-The first line contains a positive integer `v (0 ≤ v ≤ 106)`. 
>       The second line contains nine positive integers `a1, a2, ..., a9 (1 ≤ ai ≤ 105)`.
>
> Output:-Print the maximum number Igor can write on the fence. 
>       If he has too little paint for any digit (so, he cannot write anything), print -1.

In a nutshell, The problem wants us to form the largest possible number using `v` as maximum cost and has given us the cost of each digit.

The Input that my code exceeds the time limit for is:-

```
1000000
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

My Code:-

```
import sys
from sys import stdin,stdout
def findbestwithin(re):
    global cost
    s=-1;m1=re
    for i in range(len(cost)):
        if cost[i]<=m1 and i>s:
            s=i
    return s

def findminnumber():
    global cost
    s=-1;m1=sys.maxsize;co=cost
    for i in range(len(co)):
        if co[i]<m1 or(co[i]==m1 and i>s):
            s=i;m1=co[i]
    return s

m=int(input())
cost=list(map(int,input().split(' ')))


if min(cost)>m:
    print(-1)
else:
    d={}#Dictionary to store count of each digit
    t1=findminnumber()#Returns the minimum number in the List.
    t2=m//cost[t1]
    t3=m%cost[t1]#Money Left
    d[t1+1]=t2
    if t3==0:#If no money is left simply print.
        for i in d:
            for j in range(d[i]):
                stdout.write(str(i))
    else:#Try to greedily maximize each digit
        getbest=findbestwithin(cost[t1]+t3)#returns the greatest posssible number that can be selected within a given value. If none can be selected returns -1.
        while getbest!=-1:
            if getbest>t1:
                t3=t3+cost[t1]-cost[getbest]
                if getbest+1 in d:
                    d[getbest+1]+=1
                else:
                    d[getbest+1]=1
                d[t1+1]-=1
            if getbest==t1:
                break
            getbest=findbestwithin(cost[t1]+t3)

        t4=list(d.keys());t4.sort();t4.reverse();
        for i in t4:
            for j in range(d[i]):
                stdout.write(str(i))
```

My approach to the problem:-

```
Algorithm(Greedy??):-
(1)Select the cheapest digit and select as many copies of 
    it as possible(money//cost[cheapest_digit]).
    This will maximize number of digits.
(2)Iteratively maximize each of the digits from most 
    significant to least significant using the money left at repective steps.
```

The TestCase where it fails basically needs it to print '9' 10^6 times.

Using `print()` it takes 0.8s.

Using `stdout.write()` it takes 0.3s.

However it never seems to work inside the code.

I am out of ideas and will be glad if someone could point something out.

[Submission Link](http://codeforces.com/contest/349/submission/43193309)

Comment: _However it never seems to work inside the code_ What does this mean?  What does the code actually do, and how is that different from what you wanted?

Comment: The code prints the largest number that I can form. "However it never seems to work inside the code" means that although I can print '9' (10**6) times using only print() or stdout.write() in a new terminal, but it never happens inside the code, the ide freezes and crashes.

Comment: If I use an online IDE, the code runs even for the worst case of '9' (10**6) times. I get the correct output. But still it doesn't clear the time limit in the Online Judge.

Comment: Did you time the print()/stdout.write() statement locally?

Comment: I did not time it in the original code. Just opened a new terminal and noted the time it took to print '9'(or any character) (10**6) times.I'm confused if the TimeLimitException happens due to a messy algorithm or due to the large I/O. I'm pretty sure that the algorithm is correct but I can't say for certain.

Comment: In most coding competitions lazy approach does not work. You may want to look at dynamic programming to solve this.

Comment: I agree, a DP approach would be better suited but this algorithm works in O(n*10) time , since n<=10**6 how can a time limit exception occur?

Comment: You are missleaded. "Output:-Print the maximum number" means **one** number **not repeating** digits. [Edit] your Question and explaine your Inputs. Why `1000000` and `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`?

Comment: The Inputs are explained in the problem statement above. "One number" is basically a sequence of digits, Since the number of digits can be of the order of 10^6 therefore it can no longer be treated as a single number, however printing individual digits in the output stream forms the entire number. If you take a look at my algorithm you will find the greedy approach to the solution.